# Source of Gentiles given sports to distract them from harming Jews

Tags: sources-mekorot, gentiles, sport-athletics, anti-semitism, secular-culture

I heard a long time ago from a high-school [rebbe](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/593) of mine that G-d gave Gentiles sports / athletics to distract them from attacking Jews. What is the source of this concept?

Comment: Hello Dan. Psalm 19:5 is often rendered "[l]ike a groom coming from the bridal chamber; it rejoices like an athlete running a course." Interesting incontext of your question.

Comment: Not sure if this helps or not, but a noted Rabbi who used to say this was Rabbi Avigdor Miller.

Answer (score 2):

Closest idea I've ever seen was [daf 6b in Megila](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=6b&format=text), where it says Germamia (Germania), and the Medrash in Toldos adds Barbaria, were used to occupy Rome's energies so they wouldn't have time to annihilate us.